# getting the length of initiated values in a character array

Tags: c

So lets say I have a character array called **str** of size 12, and I input 1000110 in the array, with str[0] = 1, str[1] = 0 etc... I tested the array by printing it in a for loop, it works.

I then want to count how many integers are initiated in the array. In this case, the value should be: 7

Here is my code, for whatever reason, the output is 1, not 7.

```
int length;
length = 12;

int actual_length()
{
    int act_length = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if ( str[i] == 0 || str[i] == 1 )
        {
            act_length++;
        }
    }
    printf("TEST ACTUAL LENGTH: %d\n", act_length);
    return act_length;
}
```

I also tried

```
(int)str[i]
```

for the comparisons, but that did not change the outcome.

Comment: You *cannot* test whether the array was initialized by reading from it. If you read *any part* that is uninitialized, your program's behaviour is **undefined** according to the C standard.

Comment: What are they initialized to *before* you put the `1`s and `0`s into them? If nothing, then you're going to be reading from uninitialized memory in that loop, which is bad. If they're initialized to `0`, then your length will always be `12`, here.

Comment: Rether than discuss how `str` was initialized, show the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a string that consists of characters.

You need to compare against the character value:

```
 if ( str[i] == '0' || str[i] == '1' )
```